# How to get the AWS account ARN programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, account

I have an AWS account which is part of an Organization but is not the management account.
Is there a way to get in AWS the account ARN programmatically?
I know about the `GetCallerIdentityAsync()` method but this gives me the account Id. Is there a way to get the ARN in a similar (or a deferent) way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016403/how-to-get-arn-of-my-ec2-instance-using-boto3 see this can help you

Comment: @aviboy2006 thanks but I need the ARN of the account. The account ARN contains the organization's management account id (which is what I'm actually looking for)

Comment: @AmirM did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that I use, I dont know if this is the best possible way or not but I hope it helps someone.

**For Root Account:**

arn:aws:iam::12-digit-account-id:root

**For IAM User Account:**

arn:aws:iam::12-digit-account-id:iam-username

**For SSO User Account:**

arn:aws:iam::12-digit-account-id:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/federated-username